# D3 js background tab freeze while rendering to canvas

Tags: d3.js

I'm facing an issue with D3.js. When rendering data to canvas the tab freezes when it being inactive. It easily become noticeable after several minutes of tab being in a background.

I've created an [example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mercat618/4jv0bqns/61/) to reproduce the issue, it can be easily be done on local environment as well, source code follows.

```js
(() => {
  // data container script
  $(() => {
    let $dataContainer = $('.data');
    setInterval(() => {
      $dataContainer.empty();
      let numbers = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        numbers.push(randNumber);
        $dataContainer.append(`<p>${randNumber}</p>`);
      }
      $(document).trigger('data:updated', [numbers])
    }, 1000);
  });

  // actual canvas render
  $(() => {
    // boring stuff
    let base = d3.select(".viz");
    let chart = base.append("canvas")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 300);

    let context = chart.node().getContext("2d");

    let detachedContainer = document.createElement("custom");
    let dataContainer = d3.select(detachedContainer);
  
    // d3 stuff and data binding
    let drawCustom = (data) => {
      let scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data))
        .range([10, 280]);

      let dataBinding = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect")
       .data(data, (d) => { return d; });

      dataBinding.enter()
        .append("custom")
        .classed("rect", true)
        .attr("size", 0)
        .attr("x", 11)
        .attr("y", scale)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("size", 8)
        .attr("fillStyle", "red");

      dataBinding.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("size", 0)
        .remove()
    }
  
    let drawCanvas = () => {
      // clear canvas
      context.fillStyle = "#fff";
      context.rect(0,0,chart.attr("width"),chart.attr("height"));
      context.fill();

      let elements = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect");
      elements.each(function(d) {
        let node = d3.select(this);

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
        context.rect(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("size"), node.attr("size"));
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();

      });
    }
  
    $(document).on('data:updated', (e, numbers) => {
      drawCustom(numbers);
    });
    
    d3.timer(drawCanvas);
  });
})();
```

```css
.data {
  outline: 1px solid #777777;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  
}

p {
  margin: 0.7em;
}

.viz {
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  outline: 1px solid #777777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data"></div>
<div class="viz"></div>
```

I want the rendering be seamless. What can be done in this case? I believe it may be something to do with `d3.timer` function, but may be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Is it the fact that both columns have a slightly different update period?

Comment: @XavierGuihot not sure if that may be related, AFAIK d3.timer accepts a callback as an argument and handles all the updates needed, data column updated once a second, it’s slow, so shouldn’t be an issue

Comment: Related: [*"How do browsers pause/change Javascript when tab or window is not active?"*](/q/15871942) and [*"How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?"*](/q/5927284) as well as many more resources if you search for *"setInterval inactive". The reasoning is similar for `d3.timer`, which uses `requestAnimationFrame` as a default but falls back to `setInterval` in case rAF is not available.

Comment: See if this helps ? https://jsfiddle.net/jy9yxbgz/